# Как сделать генерацию рандомных чисел в диапазоне от 1 до переменной?

Tags: java, случайные-числа, scanner

Сделал программу генератора рандомных чисел. Захотел сделать так, чтобы пользователь сам мог настроить верхний порог числа. Но вот как это сделать? (пример):

```
System.out.println("Введи новое число");
Scanner userNewNum = new Scanner(System.in);
int x = userNewNum.nextInt();
Random randNum = new Random();
int randNumVar = randNum.nextInt(1 - x);
```

Я знаю, что это не работает. А как правильно?

Comment: если Вы нашли нужный ответ, отметьте его как Правильный. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

```
Random random = new Random(); 
int num1 = random.nextInt(100); // случайное целое от 0 до 99 
int num2 = 36 + random.nextInt(100 - 36); // от 36 до 99
```

Вместо 100 подставьте свой x

Answer (score 1):

В этой программе создается массив, куда записываются рандомные числа, где максимальный элемент Вы указываете сами, таким же способом можно указывать и минимальный элемент и размер массива

```
int [] array = new int[5];
        int minRandom = 1;
        int maxRandom;

       Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
       System.out.println("введите макс элемент");
       maxRandom = scanner.nextInt();

        Random random = new Random(System.currentTimeMillis());
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            array[i] = minRandom + random.nextInt(maxRandom - minRandom + 1);
            System.out.print(array[i] + ", ");
      }
```